# What is the use of 'acceskey' attribute in <input> tag?

Tags: html, spring-3

I came across an HTML page where I found an attribute 'accesskey' in an input tag.

```
<input class="button" type="submit" tabindex="1" accesskey="s" value="Log in">
```

Can somebody explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`accesskey` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/forms.html#adef-accesskey) was designed to promote accessibility by specifying a keyboard shortcut that can be used e.g. instead of clicking on a button. The reason is that people might lack a mouse or another pointing device or might have a motoric disability that prevents them from using it or makes its use very difficult.

In practice, both the shortcomings of the specification and the problems of the implementations make the attribute very [problematic](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/accesskey.html) – it tends to reduce accessibility rather than improve it. It could however be used on application-like pages to implement keyboard commands, provided that due caution is taken with the accessibility problems, or they are treated as ignorable.

Answer (score 1):

> In a web browser, an access key or accesskey allows a computer user
>   immediately to jump to a specific part of a web page via the keyboard.

[**SEE HERE**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_key)